# js to determine if iframe contains images

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, spring-mvc, iframe

I am working on an application that allows users to enroll in my program. My problem is that at the end of enrollment I generate a PDF for them to look over and accept the terms and e-sign. Sometimes the PDF server fails to stream and when that happens the iFrame just contains the alt text for the images. Is there a way to look into the iFrame and see if the images of the PDF are there or the alt text is there. That way I can keep them from proceeding and display an error message.

One Jsp looks like this

```
    <c:forEach items="${images}" var="src">
        <img src="${src}" alt="Image" />
    </c:forEach>
```

This Jsp calls a generate function which makes the pdf and turns them into images which then saves them to a remote server. The controller then returns the first jsp as the view which should populate the iFrame.

```
     <div id="image">
                    <img id="loading" src="/blah/resources/images/loading.gif" />
                    <iframe style="width: 775px; height: 600px; display: none"
                            src="blah/blah/pdf/generateImages?product=<c:out value="${fn:toLowerCase(enrollmentConversation.product.textKey)}" />&state=<c:out value="${stateCodeAbbreviation}" />&pdfGuid=<c:out value="${pdfGUIDForLookup}" />&sizeType=775/p2"
                            id="pdfIframe"
                            onLoad="jQuery('#pdfIframe').show();
                                    jQuery('#loading').hide();
                                    jQuery('.hideWhileWaiting').show();">
                    </iframe>
     </div>
```

So is there a way to look at the iFrame and say does this contain the images or does it contain alt text="Images"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `iFrame` can be another application which is cross-domain (or same application on same domain).

When you create pdf and converts them in to images, I suggest you to write SUCCESS/FAILURE entry in database.

Then from your calling application, using AJAX database call, you can easily figure out whether `pdf->image` was generated successfully or not.

Comment: Yeah I think I am going to do it with some back end validation after I make my ajax call via submit button. The streamImage method is actually catching an exception when the images fail to load so I can set a session variable or something to use for validation.